# jbpm job executor in multiple machines and one common DB

Tags: jbpm

Does jBPM4 support running job executors in multiple machines picking up job from same common DB?

If yes, if a jBPM process is started in one machine, can the job executors in other machines pick up the async jobs [Actions] of this process and execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > > can the job executors in other machines pick up the async jobs [Actions] of this process and execute?

The answer is Yes. I found out experimentally.